# History.js not firing after the initial browser window load

Tags: javascript, jquery, history.js

```
    $(function(){

        // Prepare
        var History = window.History; // Note: We are using a capital H instead of a lower h
        if ( !History.enabled ) {
             // History.js is disabled for this browser.
             // This is because we can optionally choose to support HTML4 browsers or not.
            return false;
        }

        // Bind to StateChange Event
        History.Adapter.bind(window,'statechange',function(){ // Note: We are using statechange instead of popstate
            var State = History.getState(); // Note: We are using History.getState() instead of event.state
            History.log(State.data, State.title, State.url);
        });
});
```

I'm trying use history.js as a way to track state changes (forward and backward buttons) and it seems that the window.statechange is being fired ONLY when I open a new browser window and work from there.  The initial forward and backward event is recorded but subsequent events are not.

Any ideas why that's happening?

Comment: I've tested this on Chrome 23 and Firefox 15 on Mac OSX

Answer (score 0):

I realize this question is very old. The solution is to move the statechange function outside of the body load function:

```
// Bind to StateChange Event
History.Adapter.bind(window,'statechange',function(){ // Note: We are using statechange instead of popstate
    var State = History.getState(); // Note: We are using History.getState() instead of event.state
    History.log(State.data, State.title, State.url);
});

$(function(){

    // Prepare
    var History = window.History; // Note: We are using a capital H instead of a lower h
    if ( !History.enabled ) {
         // History.js is disabled for this browser.
         // This is because we can optionally choose to support HTML4 browsers or not.
        return false;
    }

});
```